# Deleting Core Data elements with unwrapped optionals

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a Core Data Entity with a Date attribute (e.g. `current_date`. Technically, in the Class which Core Data generates for that Entity, this attribute is optional (`@NSManaged public var current_date: Date?`). However, in my app this Date is always provided, which is why in the View I am displaying this fetched Entity via a list, I am force unwrapping it with `current_date!`. This all works fine so far. However, I have added an `onDelete` to that list to be able to delete single elements and now I am getting a bug `Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. Seems to be some problem related to the deletion process - as said, that value in the data is actually never empty. Does anyone know what is the problem here?

Comment: For Core Data I would reject Xcode's *overprotection* and create the `NSManagedObject` classes manually. That gives you full control over the types. For example Core Data accepts also native collection types like `Set` for relationships which is much more convenient than *typeless-objective-c-ish* `NSSet`.

Comment: Without code is it hard to help but a more general advice, instead of force unwrapping the date attribute you could in an extension to your entity create a wrapped property of type `String`(non-optional) that either returns the formatted date or an empty string and then use this property in the UI

Comment: I think the problem is a more structural one. Even if I e.g. make the Entity attribute non-optional (`@NSManaged public var current_date: Date?`), all works fine but when I try to delete it, I get `Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1b0f19d54)`. It seems to be something around how Swift works when a Core Data Entity element is being deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Your code may not set `current_date` to nil. But if you

1. Delete a managed object object
2. Save changes
3. Try to use that same managed object reference

...then `current_date` is nil, because that's something Core Data does. This error message suggests that you are attempting to use the object after deleting it and saving changes. Ideally you should fix that, because you won't have valid data anyway. You should also avoid force-unwrapping anyway, because using it is a way of specifically requesting app crashes any time you use it.